# Не туда, куда надо добавляется класс

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Я еще учу jQuery. Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой, что не туда, куда надо добавляется класс. Нужно, чтобы новый класс был у `<p>`, а вышло у `<body>`.

```js
$(function () {
        var elem = $('body');
        elem
          .append('<p>Some text</p>'))
            .addClass('new');
});
```

```css
.new {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: elem.append('<p>Some text</p>').find('p').addClass('new');

Comment: Что мешает не осложнять и сразу добавить `.append('<p class="new">Some text</p>'))`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov , но если я сделаю большой сайт, в котором кучу абзацев, буду использовать append, prepend, before, after, то как это применить?

Comment: Добавил ответ, с реальным примером, думаю разберетесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.prependTo( "body" );` вам в помощь или `.appendTo("body");`

```js
$(function() {

  $('<p></p>')
    .html('Some text')
    .addClass('new')
    .prependTo("body");

});
```

```css
.new {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
//первый вариант:
$(function() {
  var elem = $('body');
  elem.append('<p class="new">Some text</p>');
});
//второй вариант
$(function() {
  var elem = $('body');
  elem.append('<p>Some text</p>');
  $('p').addClass('new');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Так я и думал, но если я сделаю большой сайт, в котором кучу абзацев, буду использовать append, prepend, before, after, то как это применить?

Comment: @IvanZadvornov приведите пример, кто конкретно нужно сделать? Вряд ли вы будете генерировать сайт поабзацно на js. Другое дело если текст нужно вставить где то между двух абцацев

Answer (score 3):

Цепочные вызовы jQuery основаны на том, что многие методы объекта-обертки возвращают себя. Таким образом, Вам надо добавлять элемент, используя метод правильного объекта - того, которому Вы хотите следующим вызовом добавить класс:

```
var elem = $('body');
$('<p></p>').appendTo(elem).addClass('new');
```

Comment: Тоже вариант,  но стоит добавить `.html('Some text')` Он текст тоже вставляет динамически.